# asp.net how to add a quantity selector to every item of a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm very new to ASP.NET and web applications in general. I'm trying to create an application which displays a number of materials with a quantity selector via RadioButtons for each material.
However, I can't get the radio buttons to work right. I can only select 1 button in general and not 1 for each material.

My MaterialController with a few materials:

```
public class MaterialController : Controller
{
    // GET
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var materials = from e in GetMaterialList()
            orderby e.Id
            select e;
        return View(materials);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public List<Material> GetMaterialList()
    {
        return new List<Material>
        {
            new Material {Id = 1, Name = "Material 1", Quantity = 0, Quantities = new []{0,  50, 100, 200}},
            new Material {Id = 2, Name = "Material 2", Quantity = 0, Quantities = new []{0,  50, 100, 200}},
            new Material() {Id = 3, Name = "Material 3", Quantity = 0, Quantities = new []{0,  50, 100, 200}},
            new Material() {Id = 4, Name = "Material 4", Quantity = 0, Quantities = new []{0,  50, 100, 200}}
        };
    }
}
```

My model:

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int[] Quantities { get; set; } 
}
```

Relevant part of my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MaterialOrders.Models.Material>

...
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @foreach (var quant in item.Quantities)
                        {
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Quantity, quant)
                            @quant<br/>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

I think the mistake is in the second foreach loop, but I don't know how to do it the correct way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the code in the second foreach loop with this:

```
<input id="@quant" name="@item.Name" type="radio" value="@quant">@quant                
                <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your `radiobutton` code with below code...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Quantity, quant, new { @name = item.Name })
@quant<br />
```